# pass a message from partial view to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

how can i pass a message from partial view to view?
i wanna when click on "go" button; "hello" will shown.

my view is like below:

```
 @{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }
<h2>Index</h2>
 @section bodyy
 {
    if (ViewBag.AlertMessage != null)
    {<script>alert("@ViewBag.AlertMessage");</script> }

    @Html.Action("_comment" , "home") // partial view
}
```

partial view:

```
  @{
Layout = null;
   }
   @model MvcApplication2.Models.MyClasses.commentclass
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

            @using(Ajax.BeginForm("_comment","home",new AjaxOptions{HttpMethod="Post"})) 
               {
               foreach (var item2 in  MvcApplication2.Models.MyClasses.helper.ItemsOfTbltext(Model.id))
                 {

          @Html.RadioButtonFor(z => Model.idtext, item2.id_text)<text> @item2.text</text>
                }
        <button type="submit" >  go  </button>
        }
```

my controller  is :

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _comment(tbl_download model)
    {
        shopContext db = new shopContext();
        var str = db.tbl_download.Where(z=>z.id==model.idtbl).FirstOrDefault().text;
        ViewBag.AlertMessage = "hello" ; // i cant send hello to view
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to achieve. What does your partial look like? Where are you trying to render the message? In what way isn't it working? Please improve your question.

Comment: what's `tbl_download`?

Comment: i want to show "hello" . just this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply handle **OnComplete** jquery event for AJAX form -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>    
<script>
     function OnComplete(xhr, status, error) {
         alert(xhr.responseText);
     }
 </script>
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Click", "Cal", new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod="POST", UpdateTargetId = "result", OnComplete = "OnComplete" }))
 {
     <input type="submit" value="Click"/>
 }
```

Controller Action -

```
    public ActionResult Click()
    {
        return Content("I am Ok");
    }
```

And when you execute it, a alert box with server message will be shown -

[image]

[Alternatively you can use AJAX Post using JQuery.](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/220/Posting-Data-With-jQuery-AJAX-In-ASP.NET-Razor-Web-Pages) I think this method is far more better option, because you will have more control on data formatting and display options.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the things simple. A `ViewBag` is like a dynamic box which holds whatever you put inside it. firstly clean up the mess in your razor page.

This should be you **View:**

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function DisplaySuccessMessage()
  {
    alert('@ViewBag.AlertMessage');
  }
</script>


<h2>Index</h2>

@section body
{
  @Html.Action("_comment" , "home") // partial view
}
```

**Partial view:**
As you've been using `Ajax.BeginForm()`, so you can use `OnSuccess` ajax option to return the response when your request completes.

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.MyClasses.commentclass
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("_comment","home",new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod="Post", OnSuccess="DisplaySuccessMessage"})) 
{
   foreach (var item2 in  MvcApplication2.Models.MyClasses.helper.ItemsOfTbltext(Model.id))
   {
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(z => Model.idtext, item2.id_text)<text> @item2.text</text>
   }

   <input type="submit" id="SubmitButton" value="Go" />
}
```

`_comment` is a not a good name for an `ActionResult`. You should have change that with something more meaningful. I guess it concerns your requirements but you do not need an partial view until you want to make it reusable or needed the response to be replace in ajax scenarios some times.

The response i gave does not follows the best practice either because i have to be in your requirement boundaries but it will solve your problem.

Comment: let me edit this post for more clear picture.

Comment: why are you using two `ViewModels` separately in controller and partial view ?? please elaborate your qustion by updating it with piece of `ViewModel` class also. I was stuck with editing as i could'nt figure out with this because i do not want to post a patchy response.